# Convolution from bottom right

Tags: convolution

I want to do a convolution from the bottom right and not as usual from the top left. I think conv2 of Matlab only does from the top left.

How can I do a convolution in Matlab from the bottom right?

Thank you very much for the answers.

Comment: MATLAB programming questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand your question correctly, in that you're trying to produce a mirror image of the convolution kernel (filter) and then convolve. Flip you convolution kernel. In MATLAB, you can use the `flip` command. If you flip it left-to-right, this should do it.

However, if you're simply saying that you want to use the same kernel but start the convolution process from a different point, this would not give you a different result back at all. This is one of the reasons you can do FFT based convolution.